# Generate a new format required by an Angular component from a JSON reponse

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following JSON returning from my API endpoint:

```
[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Smells like",
      "object": "",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "title": "Liquid",
          "object": {
            "objectid": 1,
            "title": "My object also have children",
            "children": []
          },
          "children": [
            {
              "id": 3,
              "title": "Loyal",
              "object": "",
              "children": []
            },
            {
              "id": 4,
              "title": "Smart",
              "object": "",
              "children": [
                {
                  "id": 5,
                  "title": "Smart",
                  "object": "",
                  "children": []
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 6,
          "title": "Just empty",
          "object": {
            "objectid": 2,
            "title": "Title of my object",
            "children": []
          },
          "children": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 10,
      "title": "Apple",
      "object": "",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": 11,
          "title": "Ink",
          "object": "",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "id": 12,
          "title": "Whatever",
          "object": "",
          "children": []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

you can copy paste it here: https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer and click Tree Viewer to see how it looks as a tree.

I need to convert that json to a format which the angular component I am using expects and it's like this:

```
[
  new Link({
    id: 1,
    label: "Smells like",
    title: "Smells like",
    object: "",
    children: [
      new Link({
        id: 2,
        label: "Liquid",
        title: "Liquid",
        object: {
          objectid: 1,
          title: "My object also have children",
          children: [],
        },
        children: [
          new Link({
            id: 3,
            label: "Loyal",
            title: "Loyal",
            object: "",
            children: [],
          }),
          new Link({
            id: 4,
            label: "Smart",
            title: "Smart",
            object: "",
            children: [
              new Link({
                id: 5,
                label: "test",
                title: "test",
                object: "",
                children: [],
              }),
            ],
          }),
        ],
      }),
      new Link({
        id: 6,
        label: "Just empty",
        title: "Just empty",
        object: { objectid: 2, title: "Title of my object", children: [] },
        children: [],
      }),
    ],
  }),
  new Link({
    id: 10,
    label: "Apple",
    title: "Apple",
    object: "",
    children: [
      new Link({ id: 11, title: "Ink", object: "", children: [] }),
      new Link({
        id: 12,
        label: "Whatever",
        title: "Whatever",
        object: "",
        children: [],
      }),
    ],
  }),
];
```

as you can see,

1. it's wrapping root nodes and children nodes with a new Link()
2. it's adding a label which can be a copy of the title
3. There might be other objects in the same json which also has "children" properties, like those "object" in the example, for which the wrapper "new link" is unwanted.

Any ideas how I can create the second structure from the first one please in typeScript ?
I mean how to iterate and find all the root nodes and the children nodes and create a new variable containing the new link wrappers wherever needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple recursion when creating nodes.
Here is a function, that should help:

```
const createLink = (itemList) => itemList.map(item => {
    new Link({
        id: item.id,
        label: item.label,
        title: item.title,
        object: item.object,
        children: item.children.length ? createLink(item.children) : []
    })
})
```

This function will iterate through all items in your response, when it will have children it will just call itself and iterate through all children.
Also, before iterating through children, you should check if it has those children, if not, just add empty array, as I see, you need those.

--- EDIT ---

I saw that there are children array in object too. I suggest you to create helper function, that will recreate object using createLink() function for children:

```
const createLink = (itemList) => itemList.map(item => {
    new Link({
        id: item.id,
        label: item.label,
        title: item.title,
        object: createObject(item.object),
        children: createLink(item.children)
    })
})

const createObject = (object) => {
    return {
        objectid: object.objectid,
        title: object.title,
        children: createLink(object.children)
    }
}
```

--- EDIT ---

I see there is a need for more explanation;

So, with createLink function you will map through all the items that you get from subscription. For example, you want to call createLink function within you subscription, and assign it to a variable, because it returns a new array:

```
this.someService().subscribe(response => {
  this.convertedTree = this.createLink(response));
}
```

Firstly what you have to do is to create Link class, so that you could create a new instance of it:

```
export class Link {
  id: string;
  label: string;
  title: string;
  object: any;
  children: any[];

  constructor(id, title, object, children) {
    this.id = id;
    this.label = title;
    this.title = title;
    this.object = object;
    this.children = children;
  }
}
```

I have updated functions so it will work as it should, also added some checks if arrays or objects are empty:

```
createLink(itemList: any): any {
    if (!itemList.length) {
      return [];
    }

    return itemList.map(item => (
      new Link(
        item.id,
        item.title,
        this.createObject(item.object),
        this.createLink(item.children)
      )));
  }

  createObject(object: any): any {
    if (!Object.keys(object).length) {
      return {};
    }

    return {
      objectid: object.objectid,
      title: object.title,
      children: this.createLink(object.children)
    }
  }
```

Now createLink function will go through you response of nodeTree and create a new instance of Link for every item, if it has children, it will create new instance of Link in children array and it will go as deep, as there are atleast on child.

Object within node will be created using createObject function it will just return empty object or object with objectId, title and children.

I have updated/ created stackblitz with everything that I just wrote:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-tree-node-bbrmgs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Sorry I don't get what I have to do? I subscribe to the service and I am getting as a response this JSON with the array of objects and arrays. 
How can I use your code to have a variable with the 'new link' wrapper before root and children nodes?

Comment: eZkkimo can you please check here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-tree-node-q7thxd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts and explain how the JSON will be converted including the 'new link' like described in the post?

Comment: @WilliamBird I have updated my answer, look into to the stackblitz also, as it could be helpful to see everything visually.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help! Appreciated!